# How to disable "shake to undo" in iPhone application written with Phonegap?

Tags: iphone, plist, cordova

[The only thing I've found](http://building-iphone-apps.labs.oreilly.com/ch07.html#addSettingForShakeToEdit) is that you have to set UIApplicationSupportsShakeToEdit to false in plist file but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: how did you set it? Did you set the correct plist? there are multiple ones in the PhoneGap Project? Basically more information is required to provide assistance

Comment: I've set it in the file named MyProject-Info.plist. This is the file where I set things i.e. regarding icons like 'Icon already includes gloss effects'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I inserted this line:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = NO;
```

in the webViewDidFinishLoad class, it worked wonders for me.

Go to the MainViewController.m and change `webViewDidFinishLoad` to look like this:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)theWebView
{
    // Black base color for background matches the native apps
    theWebView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationSupportsShakeToEdit = NO;

    return [super webViewDidFinishLoad:theWebView];
}
```